# Using Google oAuth between applications which the same user is authenticated into?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps, google-oauth

I have run into some challenges when using oAuth, and I would appriciate some expert advice!

The challenge is as follows:

**Scenario**
**1.** User A uses two seperate & external web applications (App X & App Y) synchronously.
**2.** User A authenticates into App X & App Y by using the same Google authentication credentials (OpenID / oAuth).
**3.** App X & App Y currently hold authorized Google auth tokens for User A.
**4.** App X & App Y need to share information between themselves (via REST/SOAP requests), in order to fulfill User A's requirement.
**5.** App X & App Y have a security requirement needing any external App to authenticate before accepting a REST/SOAP request.

**Question**
Can App X & App Y utilise User A's Google credentials (token) which they hold to mutally authenticate prior to generating/sending REST/SOAP requests to each other?

If there is a better way, I would appriciate your thoughts.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It depends. Does each app trust the other app if it claims authorization for a user? Or does each app need to prove to the other app it has been authorized to act for a user?

Comment: Hi Abraham. In answer to your question,  App X and App Y need to prove to each other that they have been authorised by the same user before they exchange information. The method of authorisation is Googles. Do you happen to know of a way of how they can do so?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not use token from App X to run App Y. When you run a script from the browser it pulls some auth values from a user cookie.  Even if you add these values to the header of your UrlFetchApp they will be stripped by Apps Script.
  If app Y is set to run as "me" the token from App X can be used to satisfy "Who can access the web app". This is done by sending it in the header object "Authorization":"Bearer TokenFromAppX". In App Y you can handle your own OAuth and access the users data via REST calls. See :

https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2